# How to add NSString to view in define size rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to add a sentence into my view. But the sentence is quite big. So i would like  to put it inside a defined CGRect, with several lines, and change the font size, that all sentence will be visible in this CGRect. And the font size should be as big as it is possible.

Here the code that  i am  using:

```
NSAttributedString *sentence = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"The sentence with some words" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: wordsFont,NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor yellowColor]}];


CGRect sentenceBounds;
sentenceBounds.size = [sentence size];
CGSize neededSize = CGSizeMake(MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HAIGHT);
sentenceBounds.size = neededSize;


sentenceBounds.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);

[sentence drawInRect:sentenceBounds];
```

Comment: Hmmm...I think I have some code that recursively binary-searches through font sizes until a maximum font size for an attributed string and size is found. The basis was some code I found on the web or StackOverflow (I forget). If no one posts something better or has a better solution I will dig it out and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the functionality you're looking for is included with `UILabel`. Is there a reason you can't just use that?

```
UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.attributedText = sentence;
label.frame = CGRectZero; //set desired frame here;
[self addSubview:label];
```

Comment: I can't quite remember why I rolled my own but I think this only works if the width of the string is much greater than the height and not in other cases; but that may be what OP wants.

Comment: If that is the case, you could always initialize the UILabel with a fixed width and a height of MAXFLOAT. Then call sizeToFit on the label and it will size the height appropriately.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I've tryed to use UILable  but: it shows all string in one line - i need to put my string in several lines 2 or may be 3 lines. (sorry me, my english is not fluent)